# How can one delete an entity in nhibernate having only its id and type?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-2

I am wondering how can one delete an entity having just its ID and type (as in mapping) using NHibernate 2.1?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using lazy loading, Load only creates a proxy.

```
session.Delete(session.Load(type, id));
```

With NH 2.1 you can use HQL. Not sure how it actually looks like, but something like this: **note that this is subject to SQL injection - *if possible use parametrized queries instead with SetParameter()***

```
session.Delete(string.Format("from {0} where id = {1}", type, id));
```

---

**Edit:**

For Load, you don't need to know the name of the Id column.

If you need to know it, you can get it by the NH metadata:

```
sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(type).IdentifierPropertyName
```

---

Another edit.

**`session.Delete()` is instantiating the entity**

When using session.Delete(), NH loads the entity anyway. At the beginning I didn't like it. Then I realized the advantages. If the entity is part of a complex structure using inheritance, collections or "any"-references, it is actually more efficient.

For instance, if class `A` and `B` both inherit from `Base`, it doesn't try to delete data in table `B` when the actual entity is of type `A`. This wouldn't be possible without loading the actual object. This is particularly important when there are many inherited types which also consist of many additional tables each.

The same situation is given when you have a collection of `Base`s, which happen to be all instances of `A`. When loading the collection in memory, NH knows that it doesn't need to remove any `B`-stuff.

If the entity `A` has a collection of `B`s, which contains `C`s (and so on), it doesn't try to delete any `C`s when the collection of `B`s is empty. This is only possible when reading the collection. This is particularly important when C is complex of its own, aggregating even more tables and so on.

The more complex and dynamic the structure is, the more efficient is it to load actual data instead of "blindly" deleting it.

**HQL Deletes have pitfalls**

HQL deletes to not load data to memory. But HQL-deletes aren't that smart. They basically translate the entity name to the corresponding table name and remove that from the database. Additionally, it deletes some aggregated collection data.

In simple structures, this may work well and efficient. In complex structures, not everything is deleted, leading to constraint violations or "database memory leaks".

**Conclusion**

I also tried to optimize deletion with NH. I gave up in most of the cases, because NH is still smarter, it "just works" and is usually fast enough. One of the most complex deletion algorithms I wrote is analyzing NH mapping definitions and building delete statements from that. And - no surprise - it is not possible without reading data from the database before deleting. (I just reduced it to only load primary keys.)

Comment: OK, but I cannot use this code as is, because it assumes I know the name of the Id column, which I don't. Is it possible given the actual entity CLR type, to locate the name of the Id column? After all it is in the mapping. Then, after obtaining the name of the Id column, I could execute the HQL. Thanks

Comment: Almost there, but there is still a problem. Some entities define entity-name in their mapping, but not all. The entity type is always known. The problem is that GetClassMetadata returns null when given the type of an entity defining entity-name in its mapping. So, I get null when calling sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(type). What am I to do? Thanks.

Comment: As I see it, I must have entity-name at hand. Those entities without must supply their CLR type's FullName. Am I correct?

Comment: AFAIK, there should be an overload which takes a Type as argument ?

Comment: There is, but it takes its FullName and delegates to the overload which takes a string, which in turn looks in a dictionary mapping entity-name to class metadata. Thus if an entity declares entity-name in its mapping, its metadata can only be obtained through the entity-name. Doing it by Type, like I did returns null.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You need to pass the type fullname as entity name. You'll probably need to play around a bit. I think I have also a piece of code where I go through all the class meta data and read the original type from it, putting it to a static dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Sefan, this is exactly what I did - the dictionary mapping types to entity names. It looks very strange to me that an NHibernate user has to maintain such a dictionary, so I hoped there was a better way. Looks like there is none. Thanks.

Comment: IF you write such generic code you need some common stuff between the entities, unless you need to write all this code. For instance, use an interface that includes the id, then you know its name. If you don't know it, you need to find out at runtime. it's like using reflection. Thinks can become complicates to cover many different cases.