# How to prevent NHibernate to load child collection in one-to-many relationship when removing parent

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, cascading-deletes

I have Company->Users one-to-many relationship and I would like users to be cascade deleted, when company is deleted. The problem is that NHibernate (accourding to console output: I have configured Nhibernate to log generated sql to console) first load the child collection and then performs delete on every child. How to configure NHibernate to cascade delete child collection without loading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323461/27343

There might be some space for optimization, but it is actually not that bad and in some cases even better to load children instead of trying to blindly execute some SQL delete statements.

NHibernate supports "on delete cascade" options

```
<key column="column" on-delete="cascade" />
```

but it works only under certain circumstances. It tells you when you load the mapping files.

Comment: so with this configuration DB is responsible for removing childs? is the case, if the child collection can contain a lot of entities is it better to do this in Db or still in NH?

Comment: NH will generate a "on delete cascade" foreign key. If you write the db schema yourself, you need to create such a foreign key. I guess that it always faster, but not always possible. You have to test it. At the end, it needs to remove the data from the database, which is slow anyway.