# FluentNHibernate delete entity with Composite ID

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a POCO like so:

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public virtual string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var t = obj as UserLogin;

        if (t == null)
            return false;

        return LoginProvider == t.ProviderKey && User.UserId == t.User.UserId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (LoginProvider + "|" + ProviderKey + "|" + User.UserId).GetHashCode();
    }
```

which is mapped like so:

```
public class UserLoginMap : ClassMap<UserLogin>
{
    public UserLoginMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.LoginProvider)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ProviderKey)
            .KeyReference(x => x.User, "UserId");
    }
}
```

How can I now delete one of the entities via an Nhibernation session according to it's key values without committing the cardinal sin of putting a SQL string in the code?

Answer (score 0):

*** DOESN'T SEEM WORK, HERE FOR FUTURE REFERENCE! ***

Untested, but taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4829372/613130 (the response is for the `Session.Get`, but I do hope that it works equally for `Session.Delete`, and there is even a comment `This even works with composite IDs that include referenced classes`)

You create a "fake" object tree with the ids:

```
var ul = new UserLogin { LoginProvider = "foo1", ProviderKey = "foo2", User = new User { UserId = 1 } };
Session.Delete(ul);
```

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell Theorically with NHibernate when you delete an object it does a Get and then it does the Delete. So you can do the Get manually and to the delete on the returned object. Something like: `Session.Delete(Session.Get(ul))` (see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/1323461/613130 "Another edit.")

Comment: in order for a composite operation like that to be consistent it would need to be in a serializable transaction no? Seems heavy for what must be a very common case.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell NHibernat Delete IS slow. Everyone says it. But it's slow because correctly deleting an object that is part of a graph is complex.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell See for example: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/deleting-entities-in-nhibernate